# Make the float name bold

Tags: floats, captions, lncs, newfloat

I'm using the llncs calls and introduce a new float with the `float` package. But the float name of the new float is formatted differently then the original floats, as shown in my mwe.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{lstfloat}{tb}{lop}
\floatname{lstfloat}{Listing}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstfloat}
  My listing here
 \caption{Code Caption}
\end{lstfloat}

\begin{figure}
 \centering Hello
 \caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think the problem is similar to [How to change float name to bold and separator to space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430444/how-to-change-float-name-to-bold-and-separator-to-space) but this is also not solved. People suggest the `caption` package. But as son as I load the `caption` package an extra space is introduced between the floats caption and its content. Further `caption` package overwrites the formatting of the floats defined by llncs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the caption on the top, write it before the listing.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lop,placement={tb},name=Listing]{lstfloat}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[lstfloat]{labelfont={bf},name={Listing},labelsep=period}
\begin{document}
 \begin{lstfloat}
 \caption{Code Caption}
  My listing here
\end{lstfloat}

\begin{figure}
 \centering Hello
 \caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This brings me further, answers the question as written in the title, but unfortunately does not solve my problem as it still includes the `caption` package as a dependency of `newfloat` (which I excluded below the MWE) :-(.

Comment: Nevertheless, this should not become a support thread and thus I've asked a new question with more MWEs here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479086/styling-and-spacing-around-float-caption-for-listng