# Styling and spacing around float caption for listing

Tags: floats, captions, lncs, lstlisting, newfloat

When I use the `newfloat` package instead of the `float` package there seem to be some side effects with `llncs` and/or `listings`.

*Case 1:* When I use the `float` package, the float caption of listings is not formatted correctly, but the spacing of the caption to the listing is correct, as shown in MWE #1.

*Case 2:* When I use the `newfloat` package, the float caption of listings is formatted correctly, but there is an additional spacing between the caption and the listing, as shown in MWE #2. (This spacing is not defined by the document class as can be seen at the figure environment.)

*Case 3:* This space is also introduced by the caption package, as can be seen in MWE #3. (just a guess, see the comments)

*Case 4:* Using the float option of the `listings` environment is also no option, as it leaves a space in the text, from where it is floating away. See MWE #4.

How can I get the same styling and spacing for the listing as for the figure?

**MWE #1**

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{lstfloat}{tb}{lop}
\floatname{lstfloat}{Listing}

\lstset{
   aboveskip=0pt,
   belowskip=0pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstfloat}
 \caption{Code Caption}
 \begin{lstlisting}
  My listing here seom more text here
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstfloat}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Text}
 \centering Hello
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 1 with broken caption styles but no spacing after listings caption]

**MWE #2**

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lop,placement={tb},name=Listing]{lstfloat}

\lstset{
   aboveskip=0pt,
   belowskip=0pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstfloat}
 \caption{Code Caption}
 \begin{lstlisting}
  My listing here seom more text here
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstfloat}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Text}
 \centering Hello
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 2 with correct caption styles but unwanted spacing after listings caption]

**MWE #3**

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{lstfloat}{tb}{lop}
\floatname{lstfloat}{Listing}

\lstset{
   aboveskip=0pt,
   belowskip=0pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstfloat}
 \caption{Code Caption}
 \begin{lstlisting}
  My listing here seom more text here
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstfloat}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Text}
 \centering Hello
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 3 with broken caption styles and unwanted spacing after listings caption]

**MWE #4**

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
   aboveskip=0pt,
   belowskip=0pt
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[float=tb,caption={Code Caption}]
 My listing here seom more text here
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[tb]
 \caption{Text}
 \centering Hello
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 4 uses the float of listings but this leaves a space in the text.]

*edit:* add case 4 and mwe #4
*edit2:* move the follow up notice down

This is a follow up of my question: [Make the float name bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479008/make-the-float-name-bold/479025)

Comment: The `newfloat` package does not load the `caption` package, there is no such dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I was not thorough enough. Both packages are coming from the same developer/repository. But how is this space then introduced?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I've removed the statements about the captions package. Is it better like that?

Comment: Yes, the fact that the `newfloat` package is part of the `caption` package bundle can lead to false assumptions. (Maybe it would have been a better idea to make it a separate package instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `skip=0pt` you can avoid any vertical space added by `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lop,placement={tb},name=Listing]{lstfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstfloat]{labelfont={bf},name={Listing},labelsep=period, skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
\lstset{
   aboveskip=0pt,
   belowskip=0pt
}
\usepackage{mwe}% for testing purpose only
\begin{document}
\blindtext% for testing purpose only
\begin{lstfloat}
 \caption{Code Caption}
 \begin{lstlisting}
  My listing here seom more text here
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstfloat}
\blindtext% for testing purpose only
\begin{figure}
 \caption{Text}
 \centering Hello
\end{figure}
\blindtext% for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

Here you have MWE #1 (with some dummy text) on the left and the output of my code on the right:

[image]